# Realtime serial data logging with Python - design advice

Tags: python, serial-port, software-design, software-quality

I am having to design a small program that reads the GPRMC sentence from a GPS logging device on a laptop computer. I am reading the raw values over serial connection. Once I read the raw value I will parse the GPRMC sentence (12 comma delimited values) and put them into a sqllite database so that another application can read them.

I was wanting some professional advice and some tips on implementation. The parts of the program I am wanting the most advice about are:

- Performance (does this seem like a very cpu intensive process?)
- Error checking (Need to think of all possible error states)
- Ease of updating (If I make a change  to the code tree will it be easy to update the program)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether or not the program must be embeddable. If not, there is **Redis** (http://redis.io) with a very efficient time series implementation. And there is a **Django Dash 2011** app **Staste** that does just that - http://staste.unfoldthat.com/. I didn't test it myself, but the code looks fine and the demo is promising.

Comment: As an author of staste I can add two things: 1. I haven't seen any real users of staste besides me and my friend, so the experience is very limited. 2. On the other hand, Redis really impressed me. 50-100 requests to Redis per Django page open feel like nothing compared to, for example, one small database request.